# Cuda device memory variables with OpenMP multithreading produce wrong results

Tags: c++, multithreading, cuda, openmp

I have a function in which I am calling a cuda kernel serially in a loop. This function is executed parallely in threads using OpenMP. Through each iteration, I update a variable `currentTime` with:

```
cudaMemcpyFromSymbolAsync(&currentTime, minChangeTime, sizeof(currentTime), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream_id);
```

where `minChangeTime` is computed in the kernel. Somehow, the update of this variable `currentTime` is not done properly when calling several kernels in parallel using OpenMP. I have provided a reproducible code at the end. The results I am expecting are:

```
0 65 186
1 130 251
2 195 316
3 260 381
4 325 446
...
```

But when enabling OpenMP, I do not get this difference of 121:

```
7 325 641
3 325 381
3 325 381
6 325 576
4 390 446
8 390 706
7 390 641
4 3063 446
```

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding ? If device memory variables are inappropriate here, what would then be a better variable type ?

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define CUDA_HOSTDEV __host__ __device__
#define CUDA_DEVICE __device__
#define CUDA_GLOBAL __global__
#define CUDA_CONST __constant__
#else
#define CUDA_HOSTDEV
#define CUDA_DEVICE
#define CUDA_GLOBAL
#define CUDA_CONST
#endif

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <omp.h>

#include "helper_cuda.h"
#include "helper_functions.h"

CUDA_DEVICE int minChangeTime;
CUDA_DEVICE bool foundMinimum;

CUDA_GLOBAL void reduction(
  int* cu_adjustment_time
  ){

  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  __syncthreads();
  for (unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2) {
    if (tid % (2*s) == 0){
      atomicMin(&minChangeTime, cu_adjustment_time[tid+s]);
    }
    __syncthreads();
  }
}

CUDA_GLOBAL void wh(int* cu_adjustment_time, int currentTime){
  int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  cu_adjustment_time[tid] = currentTime+tid;
}

void iteration_function(int *iRows, int time_data_index, int num_nets, cudaStream_t stream_id){
    
    int currentTime = 0;
    int limit = *iRows-1;
    int starting_point = time_data_index;
    time_data_index+=currentTime;

    int* cu_adjustment_time;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&cu_adjustment_time, sizeof(int) * (num_nets));

    limit = (*iRows) - 1;
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_id);

    int loop = 0;
    while(currentTime<limit){

        cudaMemcpyToSymbolAsync(minChangeTime, &limit, sizeof(*iRows), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream_id);
        
        wh<<<num_nets, 1, 0, stream_id>>>(
            cu_adjustment_time,
            currentTime
        );
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_id);
        
        reduction<<<1, num_nets, 0, stream_id>>>(
          cu_adjustment_time
        );
      
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_id);        
        cudaMemcpyFromSymbolAsync(&currentTime, minChangeTime, sizeof(currentTime), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream_id);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream_id);

        currentTime+=num_nets;
        time_data_index+=num_nets+1;
        
        std::cout << loop << " " << currentTime << " " << time_data_index << std::endl;
        loop++;
        
    }
    std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;

}

int main(){
    //compiled with: nvcc no_fun.cu -Xcompiler=-fopenmp -o no_fun 
    int iRows = 3000;
    int iter = 300;
    int time_data_index = 121;
    int num_nets = 64;
    cudaStream_t streams[iter];
    //#pragma omp parallel for simd schedule(dynamic) -> including this part causes undefined results
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < iter; j++){
        cudaStreamCreate(&streams[j]);
        iteration_function(&iRows, time_data_index, num_nets, streams[j]);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(streams[j]);
        cudaStreamDestroy(streams[j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not using constant memory

Comment: Indeed, I got confused with some debugging I had done before. I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiple `reduction` kernels run simultaneously, there is a race- condition with the global variable `minChangeTime`.
You need to have separate device memory for each kernel that should run in parallel. The simplest approach would be to just cudaMalloc `minChangeTime` in each thread instead of declaring it a global variable, and pass it to the kernel.

Comment: Indeed, the race condition was the problem. Thank you very much !